# What must I change to boot Linux 4.9 with Nios2?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, u-boot, buildroot, nios

I read the [manual](https://rocketboards.org/foswiki/view/Documentation/NiosIILinuxUserManual) and used buildroot the create the images

```
$ ls buildroot/output/images/
rootfs.cpio  rootfs.jffs2  rootfs.tar
```

Then I built u-boot:

```
~/nios2/u-boot-socfpga$ ls -al u-boot
-rwxrwxr-x 1 developer developer 852924 apr  8 14:00 u-boot
```

Then I do `make menuconfig` and choose the path to the buildroot files

[image]

Now I build the vmImage.

```
  OBJCOPY arch/nios2/boot/vmlinux.bin
  GZIP    arch/nios2/boot/vmlinux.gz
  UIMAGE  arch/nios2/boot/vmImage
Image Name:   Linux-4.9.0-00104-g84d4f8a-dirty
Created:      Sat Apr  8 14:02:22 2017
Image Type:   NIOS II Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    7237729 Bytes = 7068.09 kB = 6.90 MB
Load Address: c0000000
Entry Point:  c0000000
Kernel: arch/nios2/boot/vmImage is ready
```

I wonder why I can't run any of the generated images now. Where is the faulty method? It all compiles but my file system doesn't come in place when I download the files to the [fpga](/questions/tagged/fpga):

```
$ nios2-download -g /home/developer/nios2/linux4/vmlinux
Using cable "USB-Blaster [2-1]", device 1, instance 0x00
Pausing target processor: OK
Initializing CPU cache (if present)
OK
Downloaded 8504KB in 43.7s (194.5KB/s)
Verified OK                         
Starting processor at address 0xC0000000
```

It stops with kernel panic:

```
$ nios2-terminal 
nios2-terminal: connected to hardware target using JTAG UART on cable
nios2-terminal: "USB-Blaster [2-1]", device 1, instance 0
nios2-terminal: (Use the IDE stop button or Ctrl-C to terminate)

Linux version 4.9.0-00104-g84d4f8a-dirty (developer@1604) (gcc version 6.2.0 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2016.11-32) ) #49 Sat Apr 8 14:02:21 CEST 2017
bootconsole [early0] enabled
early_console initialized at 0xe8001440
On node 0 totalpages: 32768
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c084e52c, node_mem_map c0883b80
  Normal zone: 256 pages used for memmap
  Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
  Normal zone: 32768 pages, LIFO batch:7
pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
Kernel command line: debug console=ttyAL0,115200
PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 121196K/131072K available (2233K kernel code, 66K rwdata, 352K rodata, 5852K init, 197K bss, 9876K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS:64 nr_irqs:64 0
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������clocksource: nios2-clksrc: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 38225208935 ns
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 100.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=50000)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
cpu cpu0: Error -2 creating of_node link
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275000 ns
�random: fast init done
clocksource: Switched to clocksource nios2-clksrc
random: crng init done
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=15 bucket_order=0
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 254)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
�8001440.serial: ttyJ0 at MMIO 0x8001440 (irq = 2, base_baud = 0) is a Altera JTAG UART
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
Failed to create /dev/root: -2
VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -2
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must point the initramfs source file to the cpio archive, so `/home/developer/nios2/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.cpio`.

Even easier is to let Buildroot build your kernel and choose the initramfs filesystem. Then Buildroot will take care of linking the initramfs into the kernel.